# Matplotlib : plt.legend() Throwing TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I am building a histogram from a pd.DataFrame.
I am attempting to customize the legend, however, any call to plt.legend() throws a TypeError.  Everything else regarding the graph is working as intended.  Any thoughts as to why?

Code:

```
df.plot(x='Bucket', 
             kind='bar', 
             stacked=True,
             figsize=(10, 10),
          )


plt.ylabel('Emails', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Character Length of Emails', fontsize=20)
plt.title('Email Topics vs Email Length', fontsize=30)
plt.xticks(rotation = 25, fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(rotation = 25, fontsize=15)

plt.legend()
```

Error :

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-554-876a190bbc34> in <module>
     22 plt.yticks(rotation = 25, fontsize=15)
     23 
---> 24 plt.legend()
     25 
     26 

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The same error is thrown when I call

```
plt.legend([])
plt.legend(loc='upper center')
```

etc.

Comment: Did you define a list as `legend`? What is the rest of your code?

Comment: we need to see all of your code in order to help you debug. Additionally, please include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors. As Michael S. points out - you must have modified the plt.legend object somehow, so we can't answer this without seeing a full example.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thank you for the feedback, I added the rest of my code to create the histogram, and the complete error message.  I did not define a list as legend.

Comment: I just tried your provided code (by making a mock dataframe called `df`) and it worked fine. You aren't including all of your code or, at some point, you set `legend` equal to something. Try restarting your kernel and running the code again.

Comment: @MichaelS. Will do, really appreciate it thank you!

Comment: Specific case where a [MCVE] is needed. Also what is `df` and what is your version of pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do this somewhere?

```
plt.legend = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If you did, remove that line of code. I was able to duplicate your error by doing the below code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Bucket":[1,2,3,4,5], "Y":[1,2,3,4,5]})

df.plot(x='Bucket', 
        kind='bar', 
        stacked=True,
        figsize=(10, 10),
       )

plt.legend = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.ylabel('Emails', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Character Length of Emails', fontsize=20)
plt.title('Email Topics vs Email Length', fontsize=30)
plt.xticks(rotation = 25, fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(rotation = 25, fontsize=15)

plt.legend()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26684/882015504.py in <module>
     14 plt.yticks(rotation = 25, fontsize=15)
     15 
---> 16 plt.legend()

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Nice shot seems to be a good candidate for this error.